# Why CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE causes errors with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp, cppunit, bjam, boost-build

Operational system = Ubuntu.

bjam usage = TRUE.

I want to optimize my unit testing system with help of OpenMP.

bjam script file:

```
lib my_lib
    :
        [ glob sources/*.cpp ]
    :
        <link>static
    ;


    ...

explicit my_project ;
unit-test my_project
    :
        [ glob UnitTests/*.cpp ]        
        my_lib
    :
    <linkflags>-fopenmp
    <cflags>-fopenmp
    ;
```

The part of my code:

```
   for(j = 0; j < AMOUNT; j++)
   {
      #pragma omp parallel for
      for(i = 0; i < 0x10000; ++i)
      {
         ...
         try
         {
            variable1 = func1();
            variable2 = func2();
        //variable1 and variable 2 must be equal
            CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE("OLOLO", variable1 == variable2);

         }
         catch (const std::logic_error& exception)
         {
            std::cerr << exception.what() << std::endl;
            CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE("OLOLO", 0);
         }
         catch (const std::runtime_error & exception)
         {
            std::cerr << exception.what() << std::endl;
            CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE("OLOLO", 0);
         }

      }

   }
```

When I launch my testing system it exits with error:

```
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

I comment lines CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE:

```
   for(j = 0; j < AMOUNT; j++)
   {
      #pragma omp parallel for
      for(i = 0; i < 0x10000; ++i)
      {
         ...
         try
         {
            variable1 = func1();
            variable2 = func2();
            //CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE("OLOLO", variable1 == variable2);

         }
         catch (const std::logic_error& exception)
         {
            std::cerr << exception.what() << std::endl;
            //CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE("OLOLO", 0);
         }
         catch (const std::runtime_error & exception)
         {
            std::cerr << exception.what() << std::endl;
            //CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE("OLOLO", 0);
         }

      }

   }
```

And it works in the way just I need. But I need CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE to output information in case of wrong results.
Why CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE causes errors and what should I do to get rid of these errors.

Answer (score 1):

CPPUNIT works by stopping the program when it encounters an error. To output the information in case of wrong results instead of stopping the program then you must configure the XmlOutputter and create a TestRunner that uses it.

For example:

```
// Create the event manager and test controller
CPPUNIT_NS::TestResult controller;

// Add a listener that colllects test result
CPPUNIT_NS::TestResultCollector result;
controller.addListener( &result );

// Add a listener that print dots as test run.
CPPUNIT_NS::BriefTestProgressListener progress;
controller.addListener( &progress );

// Add the top suite to the test runner
CPPUNIT_NS::TextUi::TestRunner runner;
CPPUNIT_NS::Test *suite = CPPUNIT_NS::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest();
runner.addTest( suite );

runner.setOutputter( new CppUnit::XmlOutputter( &runner.result(),
                                                       std::cerr ) );

runner.run( testPath, false, true, true );

std::cout << "Test done" << std::endl;
exit( result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1 );
```

That way you have a test runner that outputs to an xml stream instead of stopping the test.

Hope it helps